# Facebook Graph API - get all comments I've ever made

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any possible way to do this?  I've made a lot of comments that I really want to archive on my own (so they'll be searchable and I can find what I've said in the past).  Some of them were made in private groups, some of them were made in public groups, and some were made on personal posts.

Comment: No there are no API for that.